# Fazer uma mudança em uma div ao marcar um checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Alguém sabe como eu faço para alterar uma `div` ou `label` ao marcar um `checkbox` exemplo tenho esse código aqui.

```
<label style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
   <div class="adicionalch bg-yellow">
       Nutella <input type="checkbox" name="adicional[]" value="3.00" id="3.00">
  </div>
</label>
```

com uma classe `bg-yellow`, ao marcar o `checkbox`, ele altere para outra classe ou adicione alguma formatação css..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
function mudaDiv(el) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("bg-yellow")[0].style.backgroundColor = el.checked ? "blue" : "";
}
```

```html
<label style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
   <div class="adicionalch bg-yellow">
       Nutella <input type="checkbox" name="adicional[]" value="3.00" id="3.00" onclick="mudaDiv(this);">
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Menino bunito! +1

Answer (score 3):

É isso que você quer?

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('.checkbox').change(function() {
     var $that = $(this),
         $div = $that.closest('.bg-yellow');
    
        if ($that.is(':checked')) {
             $div.css('background-color', 'yellow');     
        } else {
            $div.css('background-color', '');
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div class="adicionalch bg-yellow">
    Nutella <input type="checkbox" name="adicional[]" value="3.00" id="3.00" class="checkbox"></div>
</label>
```

Ao invés de pegar pelo `id`, tive que criar uma `classe`, pois a formatação do `id` da sua checkbox não é compatível com seletor do jQuery.

Comment: Tem de ver se ele usa jQuery ou ele esqueceu de colocar a _tag_, ;)

Comment: Responde aí sem jQuery, porque eu estou com preguiça ;p